# Restore default KDE launch button

Tags: kubuntu, kde, interface, button

Previously Kubuntu had the default KDE button of gears with the letter K. Later Kubuntu default theme's button changed to the Kubuntu logotype. How can I change this application menu button back to the one with the letter K?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my 18.04 kubuntu, I can right-click the application menu button, choose "Configure Application Launcher" which opens a window, click on the icon in the window, and then click on "Choose..." and choose from the installed icons.

I did this for my application menu button, I can't remember what it was before I changed it, but it is now a colourful K and gears.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find the black and white KDE gears though, only blue ones.